# Replace dot from 2 letters

Tags: php

I want something like this:

```
$name = str_replace(".", " ", $name);
```

but if I have this name:

> Text.Text.text.text.Text.5.0.1

I want to remove the dots only from letters and from "t.5".
Text must result:

> Text Text text text Text 5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `preg_replace('/([^\d])\./', '$1 ', $name)`

`/([^\d])\./` matches a non-digit followed by a `.`.  Replaces it with `$1`, the non-digit you found, followed by a space.

Edit: given refined requirement from comment below, that "." are removed only if there's a non-digit before OR after, answer is (requires 2 statements):

```
$name = preg_replace('/([^\d])\./', '$1 ', $name);
$name = preg_replace('/\.([^\d])/', ' $1', $name);
```

Comment: Works but if I have 7.H doesn't replace. I can use another preg_replace. But I don't know what

Comment: What exactly are your rules for removing the "."?  I understood it to be remove all "." unless PREceded by ANY digit.  Is that correct or is it more specific such as only if the digits are "5" or "0"?  "7.H" is not a "

Comment: Look. I have this name: 
 Game.of.Thrones.S05E07.HDTV.x264-ASAP
and I want to remove all dots from that name. The numbers and letters can be different. I try your code. The result:
 Game of Thrones S05E07.HDTV x264-ASAP

Comment: If you want to remove ALL dots, your code in your original post will do that.  But I think you want to keep some of the dots.  Which dots do you want to keep.

Comment: But If I have Program.Version.5.3.2 I want to result:
Program Version 5.3.2

Comment: I want to keep dots only between numbers

Comment: I think it is better to use real example as confusion often occur on obscurity

Comment: So, I believe requirement is keep the `.` if there is a digit before AND after it.  In other words, replace `.` if a non-digit is before OR after it.  This needs two PHP statements:

Comment: preg_replace('/([^\d])\./', '$1 ', $name); preg_replace('/\.([^\d])/', '$1 ', $name);

Comment: It works but here $name = preg_replace('/\.([^\d])/', ' $1', $name); I moved the space before $1. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, thanks, (so hard to write code in these little comment boxes).  I've updated answer above.